# CSS Width not working properly

Tags: html, css

not sure if you can help me with this because the HTML code is fairly confusing and I just can't seem to figure this out... I just copied it straight from the site I am working on... but I am trying to get everything to be `width = 210px` but as you can see there are certain elements that stretch beyond that...

Really what I have figured out is all I need/want to do is fix the lines that say `HTMLText-V2[1]` and `MailForm-V2`

**Here is my fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/ney2V/

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Tables? Seriously? Dude, it's 2013. Check out the box model!

Comment: Dude seriously, I didn't create the initial website. Just said I was working on it.

Comment: @BenM However, I am curious about this box model you speak of, got a link for anything on it? but also... can't edit any of the html, I just have access to the css.

Comment: @metsales The box model is a subject in CSS that concerns the layout of HTML elements.  CSS is preferable to tables for layout nowadays.  Here's a good tutorial for the future: http://htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/

Comment: He's referring to using CSS for layout, a method that gained a lot of traction 10 years ago with the CSS Zen Garden. Here's an article from the zen garden's creator: http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2013/05/07/10_years/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your elements have some images (namely the Verb_Seperator.gif) that are forcing wider widths than what your table is set at, so they bust out of your table cells. CSS will not help you here.

It's a bit difficult to figure out the optimal setup since we don't have all the content, but I've moved those image elements into their own table rows, which allows it to break a little nicer.

http://jsfiddle.net/nathanlong/9h5FR/1/

Basically what was:

```
<tr>
  <td>content</td><td>content</td>
</tr>
```

is now:

```
<tr>
  <td>content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>content</td>
</tr>
```

Also, take a look at the colspan property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) to account for unused columns to make everything match nicely.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, but it helps. Thanks for the help!